# Flask-Mysql Python 1064 error when update table into Mysql

Tags: python, sql-update, mysql-error-1064, flask-mysql

Been stuck whole day with this update mysql table error while build a web app with Flask python.

(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE 'user_id'='28'' at line 1")

Tried removing comma and adding `` according to solution of similar problems in Stackoverflow but it's not working.

```
@app.route('/update')
def update():
    try:
        conn = mysql.connect()
        update = conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        sql = "UPDATE user SET user_photo=%s, WHERE user_id=%s"
        _path="User.30.1.jpg"
        _id="28"
        data = (_path,_id)
        update.execute(sql,data)
        conn.commit()
        return render_template('training.html')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the comma from the sql variable:

```
sql = "UPDATE user SET user_photo=%s WHERE user_id=%s"
```